# How can I get the value of a specific attribute on mousehover?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am doing a **mousehover** event on a **innerhtml** content. In that content I have highlighted certain words. That highlighted words have title attribute with a value. I want to get the particular title value of the content which I hover. I want to get the value through mousehover event on the ts

The plain **innerhtml** content is stored on a variable **text** in the ts for your reference in case you wanna check it

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zc1zzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Minor logic to your `onHover()` method will make it work.

```
  onHover(e) {
    if (!!e.target && e.target.title != null) {
      console.log(e.target.title);
    } else {
      //No Title
    }
  }
```